# Salesforce World Tour @ CeBIT 2016

Tags: discussion, sf-worldtour, salesforce

Salesforce World Tour 2016 has started! Is someone going to go there?

It seems to be a great event for all who are interested in Salesforce (developers, consultants, start-upers etc). 
I am going to go there on Wednesday (16 Mar.) so wish me a lot of fun! :) PS. Pics and reports are on my twitter.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out who in the top 25 changed their user name...Mastor! Cropredy did recently too but that was easier to figure out.

Comment: @AdrianLarson :) Just a little bit fresh wind for the profile

Comment: Looking sharp! You must have taken that at the world tour! ;)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Ohh no,  just a few years ago. World tour pics are on my twitter :P